# Stored procedure with optional OFFSET query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to get data and stored procedure is as below -

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE SPProfileScholarshipReports 
@scholarshipGroupCode nvarchar(50),
@statuses nvarchar(350),
@studentSearch nvarchar(100),
@fromDateString nvarchar(50),
@toDateString nvarchar(50),
@studentTypeFilter nvarchar(50),
@offsetFrom INT,
@offsetTo INT,
@sortColumn nvarchar(50),
@sortOrder nvarchar(10),
@isExportToExcel BIT
AS 
 Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- variable declaration
 declare @Separator varchar(1)= ',' 
 DECLARE @XML XML 
 declare @studentType varchar(20)= null 
 IF(@studentSearch = '')
    set @studentSearch = null 
 IF(@studentTypeFilter = 'new')
    set @studentType = 'false'
 else if(@studentTypeFilter = 'continuing')
    set @studentType = 'true'
 else set @studentType = null 

 if(@sortOrder = '' or @sortOrder is null)
    set @sortOrder = ' DESC ' 
 else if(@sortOrder = 'true')
    set @sortOrder = 'ASC'
 else
    set @sortOrder = 'DESC'
    -- accept comma separated parameters and convert them to use for in 
clause condition
   declare @tPsListViewStatus TABLE (val nvarchar(3600))
    IF(@statuses is not null and @statuses<>'' and @statuses like '%,%')
      BEGIN
        set @statuses = replace(replace(replace(replace(@statuses,' , ',','),', ',','),' ,',','),' ','')
    SET @XML = CAST( ('<i>' + REPLACE(@statuses, @Separator, '</i><i>') + '</i>') AS XML)
    INSERT INTO @tPsListViewStatus
      select    t.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')
      FROM  @XML.nodes('i') AS t(i)
      WHERE t.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') <> ''
  END
            select * from
                (
                    select
                        (nm.LastName+' ' + nm.FirstName) as studentName,
                        pi.value,
                        ps.isContinuing,
                        sc.name as scholarshipName,
                        ps.status,
                        ps.CreatedDate,
                        ps.summary,
                        ps.effectiveDate,
                        ps.expiryDate,
                        sc.id as scholarshipId, 
                        (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + t.code FROM Academic_Term t WHERE t.effectiveDate >= ps.effectiveDate
                        and t.expiryDate <= ps.expiryDate and t.active = 'true' and t.code not like '%.%' and t.code not like '%COFA%'
                        and t.code not like '%NUR%' order BY t.code asc FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) as code,
                        (SELECT SUM( convert( decimal( 10, 2 ), AmountAwarded )) as athleticAmount FROM profile_scholarship
                        WHERE (Status IN(select * from @tPsListViewStatus)) and id= ps.id) AS PS_amountAwarded,
                        (SELECT DISTINCT(fs1.code) 
                         FROM profile_scholarship_term pst LEFT OUTER JOIN fund_source_academic_term fsat ON pst.FundSourceAcademicTermId=fsat.Id 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN fund_source fs1 ON fsat.FundSourceId=fs1.Id WHERE ps.Id = pst.ProfileScholarshipId) as fundSourceCode,
                        ps.studentProgramId,
                        ps.id as psId,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                            PARTITION by ps.scholarshipId,
                            ps.profileId,
                            ps.status
                        ORDER BY
                            ps.EffectiveDate desc,
                            ps.ExpiryDate desc,
                            ps.CreatedDate desc
                        ) AS RowNumber,
                        ps.profileId,
                        ps.FAStudentAcademicYearId
                    from
                        profile_scholarship ps
                    INNER JOIN scholarship sc on
                        ps.ScholarshipId = sc.id
                    INNER JOIN dbo.scholarship_sub_group ssg on
                        sc.ScholarshipSubGroupId = ssg.Id
                    INNER JOIN dbo.scholarship_group sg on
                        ssg.ScholarshipGroupId = sg.Id
                    INNER JOIN name nm on
                        ps.ProfileId = nm.profileId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.profile_identity pi on
                        ps.ProfileId = pi.ProfileId
                    where
                        sg.code = @scholarshipGroupCode and ps.SystemIdentified = 'SIS' 
                        and (ps.Status  IN(select * from @tPsListViewStatus)) 
                        AND((ps.status = 'DELETED' AND ps.summary like '%CVUE_DELETE%') OR (ps.status != 'DELETED'))
                        and pi.type = 'STUDENT_NUMBER'
                        and(ps.isContinuing IN(@studentType) or ISNULL(@studentType,'')= '') 
                        and ps.CreatedDate BETWEEN @fromDateString AND @toDateString
                        ) as resultList
            where resultList.rowNumber = 1 and (ISNULL(@studentSearch,'')= ''  or resultList.studentName like '%' + @studentSearch + '%'  
                    or resultList.value like '%' + @studentSearch + '%') 
            order by
            case 
                when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
                when @sortColumn = 'modified' then resultList.CreatedDate end DESC,
            case
                when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
                when @sortColumn = 'modified' then resultList.CreatedDate end ASC,
            case 
                when @sortColumn = '' then resultList.CreatedDate end 
            DESC
            OFFSET @offsetFrom ROWS FETCH NEXT @offsetTo ROWS ONLY
END
```

In this query I want to remove "OFFSET @offsetFrom ROWS FETCH NEXT @offsetTo ROWS ONLY" if @isExportToExcel is true. the value of @isExportToExcel is being passed from java code. I tried with below CASE statement but it is not working

```
Case 
  when @isExportToExcel = 0 then 'OFFSET @offsetFrom ROWS FETCH NEXT @offsetTo ROWS ONLY' END
```

But this is not working and I am always getting completed data and pagination is not working with this

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an inline CASE expression to determine if there will be an OFFSET or not.

I can think of three ways you can do this:

One is to write your entire query with dynamic sql.

The other is to split the logic:

```
IF @isExportToExcel = 0
  --Do the query with the OFFSET
ELSE
  --Do the query without OFFSET
```

The third is to re-populate the parameters based on the boolean:

```
IF @isExportToExcel = 1
  BEGIN
  SET @offsetFrom = 0;
  SET @offsetTo = {Query that gets the total count of rows that will be returned by the main query}
  END

--then execute your main query as is.
```